# Android change Edit text cursor blink rate

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to change the blink rate of edit text cursor.

I want to **increase the blink rate**.

I tried to search to not able to find any solution to it.
Is there is any way I can change the blink rate of edit text cursor in android.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible through the public api. The blinking rate is defined by the constant `BLINK` defined in the `Editor` class

```
/**
 * Helper class used by TextView to handle editable text views.
 *
 * @hide
 */
public class Editor {
   private static final String TAG = "Editor";
   static final boolean DEBUG_UNDO = false;

   static final int BLINK = 500;
```

`TextView` keeps a reference to the `Editor` object